# Integrating a Nib based SQL3 Lite project into a tabbed bar

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sqlite

I have been looking around for a while and finally found a SQL Lite tutorial that perfectly suits my needs. I downloaded the source code from it.

This code however had plenty of depreciated code that I in turn fixed. Here is a link to my updated project. [(HERE)](http://www.blakeloizides.co.za/sql.zip)

I have had quite a bit of experience integrating xib based projects into a tab bar project. But I'm stuck right at the beginning because in just about every file in this project there is a reference to **SQLAppDelegate** which is the app delegate of the SQL Project.

The problem I am having is that I have a storyboard project and already have an app delegate. If I included the code from SQLAppDelegate.h and SQLAppDelegate.m in my AppDelegate.h and AppDelegate.m of the storyboard project and include the code from RootViewController in the Tutorial project into my storyboard tabbar project view controller files and deleted RootViewController.xib and kept the rest of the files in my project, would that work?

E.g I would get rid of SQLAppDelegate.h and SQLAppDelegate.m and MainWindow.xib in the tutorial and integrate that code into my storyboard Appdelegate.h and AppDelegate.m.

Then I would take all the other files in the tutorial project and include then in my project with the correct frameworks. I would delete RootViewController.xib and keep RootViewController.h and .m , Then I would Integrate the setup of RootViewController.xib into my Tab I wanted it in my Tabbar storyboard. and make the correct references to it. 
I would call that tab RootViewController in my storyboard.

I know I can include .xib files in my storyboard tabbar project and reference them from my storyboard. It works I've done it.

Would including the code inside SQLAppDelegate into my AppDelegate interfere with the code in the rest of my tabs?

Or can I just include SQLAppDelegate and the rest of the files into my project and reference them then delete MainWindow and _window code from my project and then make the relevant in my tab storyboard project connect to SQLAppDelegate?

This mite sound a bit confusing?

**UPDATE**
Okay... after trying to integrate it myself I came across a number of issues like

```
SQLAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SQLAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Does not work in Arc and all in all I got about 10 errors and all I did was include the files within the tutorial project in my Storyboard tabbar project.

Who would have thought trying to use SQLite in a Storyboard Tabbar project was so difficult?

Is there any example of a Storyboard Tabbar Example out there that uses SQLite in one of the tabs?

The functionality of this project was so perfect. Sigh.

[image]

Comment: I found a Christmas Kepper App from http://www.raywenderlich.com/6603/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 . A great tutorial, I downloaded the tutorial and aside from a few lines of depreciated code and 1 warning which I managed to fix, It works perfectly for what I want. :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a Christmas Kepper App from raywenderlich.com/6603/basic-security-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2 . A great tutorial, I downloaded the tutorial and aside from a few lines of depreciated code and 1 warning which I managed to fix, It works perfectly for what I want. :D